# What is the proper technique to draw a gun?

Tags: self-defense, firearms

I've been toying with an airsoft pistol. The mental context is reacting to a home invasion a la [Memento](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1): multiple armed but misinformed that the flat is going to be empty assailants, very aggressive for fear of leaving alive witnesses*.

It is my observation that in close quarters (< 5m) a knife is superior to a gun because it is drawn a little quicker and is somewhat more useful halfway drawn (hammer strikes to the temples, arm hooking, jabs to the face)**.

Another observation is that a gun can be drawn from a holster or from the table in various ways. One of them is to draw it close to the body and THEN, IF some clearance is guaranteed, aim and brace for the recoil.

How does this fit into the paradigm of dynamic shooting? What are some sources to get educated on it? What is the fastest way to draw upon someone at 9 o'clock***?

<sub>* - who needs computer games when you can play them in your head</sub>
<sub>** - knife == switchblade here; halfway drawn == in your hand but the blade has not been deployed</sub>
<sub>*** - directly to your left</sub>

Comment: I'm running this past summer of my friends into guns, but https://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Tactical-Quickdraw-With-a-Pistol?amp=1 looks like a good start.

Comment: I have heard before from a serving police officer in the UK who was an instructor in shorinji kempo that a knife is indeed more dangerous than a gun at very very close quarters.  I would not want to have to face either tbh.

Answer (score 5):

I attended last year a training defence against weapons.
Guns are here restricted, so this it isn't trained often.

We started with the course with the use of guns. One had it, the other one closed in, step by step. Not everyone had been in the military.

In the training everyone aimed with long arms while the opponent had distance.
At one point all took the gun to the side of the body, to keep it out of reach of the opponent. At that distance there is no need to aim carefully, you hit anyway.

Keep this in mind for your case of 'home invasion'.
Keep the gun out of reach, because you have not the distance to aim.
To draw a gun fast, you have to have it always prepared and in reach.
That means, it is also in reach for children or silly friends.

---

I'm sure, the danger of 'home invasion' is far lower than the danger of fatal accidents. Prepare for more likely situations.

By the way, a gun isn't the tool of choice.
The distance between 'death' to 'no effect for the next five minutes' is to close.
A Stick or a heavy bible is more likely in reach.
'Environment use' training helps you more likely. Early Jackie Chan movies show what I mean.

Comment: I'd definitely take a katana over a firearm if the invader has to come around a tight corner—they still have to aim, but katana just cuts.

Comment: @DukeZhou perhaps I misunderstood Bru's answer. My reading is "in tight quarters, have one arm free for hand combat(probably stretched foreward to clear space), have the other arm at the waist with the gun aimed forward". Zero aiming. The katana guy cuts the hand off, gets 3 holes in the chest and stomach.

Comment: @Vorac
Your reading is perfectly right. Thanks.

Comment: @Vorac one advantage to blades is you still have control even after penetrating the opponent's body, unlike bullets where you lose control the moment it leaves the barrel, and can bounce around inside the body, or exit cleanly without damaging any major organs.  (That said, I should qualify that, in a home defense situation, my actual optimal choice would be a short-barreled shotgun so I don't even have to worry about aiming—just pointing it in the general direction;)